# Using 'os' package to search for a csv in downloads directory and then automatically read it with 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, operating-system

I want it to ask the user the name of two csv archives, and os.listdir() to look for they, and once find open they with pandas, maybe os.listdir() isn t what i really need?

you can avoid tkinter part, the problem is the defined function

````
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import os

def search_csv():
    csv_file1 = entry1.get()
    csv_file2 = entry2.get()
    found_files = 0
    for file in os.listdir("C:\Users\Chisco\Downloads"):
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            if file == csv_file1:
                df1 = pd.read_csv(file)
                found_files += 1
            elif file == csv_file2:
                df2 = pd.read_csv(file)
                found_files += 1
            if found_files == 2:
                break
    if found_files < 2:
        not_found = []
        if found_files == 0:
            not_found = [csv_file1, csv_file2]
        elif csv_file1 not in locals():
            not_found.append(csv_file1)
        elif csv_file2 not in locals():
            not_found.append(csv_file2)
        print(f"{' and '.join(not_found)} not found.")
    else:
        print(df1)
        print(df2)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("CSV Search")

label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter first CSV File Name:")
label1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter second CSV File Name:")
label2.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()

search_button = tk.Button(root, text="Search", command=search_csv)
search_button.pack()

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: What's wrong about using `os.listdir` ? Do you receive any errors ?

Comment: Probably a `SyntaxError: (unicode error)` because `\Users` is not correctly escaped. Use: `r"C:\Users\Chisco\Downloads"` (raw strings) or `"C:\\Users\\Chisco\\Downloads"` (escape characters) or `"C:/Users/Chisco/Downloads"` (posix path)

Comment: at first the path gave me an error, now thanks to corralien that is fixed, but it returns that it does not find the files and they are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey i have solved the problem with this new code:

````
import os
import pandas as pd

def search_csv():
    csv_file1 = entry1.get()
    csv_file2 = entry2.get()
    found_files = 0
    # Get the current user's "Downloads" directory
    downloads_dir = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(downloads_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                if file == csv_file1:
                    file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                    df1 = pd.read_csv(file_path)
                    found_files += 1
                elif file == csv_file2:
                    file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                    df2 = pd.read_csv(file_path)
                    found_files += 1
                if found_files == 2:
                    break
    if found_files < 2:
        not_found = []
        if found_files == 0:
            not_found = [csv_file1, csv_file2]
        elif csv_file1 not in locals():
            not_found.append(csv_file1)
        elif csv_file2 not in locals():
            not_found.append(csv_file2)
        print(f"{' and '.join(not_found)} not found in {downloads_dir}.")
    else:
        print('esto es viento:',df1)
        print('esto es rumbo:',df2)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("CSV Search")

label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter first CSV File Name:")
label1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter second CSV File Name:")
label2.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()

search_button = tk.Button(root, text="Search", command=search_csv)
search_button.pack()

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.